# How to change Keycloak logo on the Admin console page in keycloak.v2 theme

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to find a way to replace Keycloak image on the Admin console page using Keycloak.v2 theme which is the default theme starting from Keycloak 19.

Note that replacing `themes\keycloak.v2\account\resources\public\logo.svg` didn't really help.

Answer (score 6):

In Keycloak, one of the ways you can change the Keycloak logo is by overriding a theme.  The benefit of doing it this way over forking and building the entire keycloak-admin-ui repo is you can control and focus only on customizing the components you want, cutting down the size of your new theme and reducing unnecessary duplication.

For your specific use-case (tested in Keycloak 20.0.1), I did the following to change the Keycloak Logo on the Admin Console Page:

1. Per the [Theme Guide for Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes), custom themes can be added to keycloak by placing them into `/opt/keycloak/themes`. After Keycloak starts the theme can then be selected in the **Realm Settings**. Therefore, I created a new folder in `/opt/keycloak/themes` for my custom theme, called `myCustomTheme`.
2. The new folder will contain the theme definition for different parts of Keycloak.  Since we only care about changing the logo in the Admin Console, we create a folder in `/opt/keycloak/themes/myCustomTheme` for overriding the Admin Console Theme.  Per the [defined set of theme types](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#theme-types), this folder should be called `admin`.  This is so that when you are selecting themes in **Realm Settings** within the **Admin Console**, the **MyCustomTheme** option will be listed under the **Admin Console** section (see images below).
3. Inside of `/opt/keycloak/themes/myCustomTheme/admin` is where the theme overriding begins. A configuration file called `theme.properties` should be created. This file is the first thing read by Keycloak when loading your theme and contains information about the theme environment. For more detailed information, see the description of [Theme Properties](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#theme-properties).

   - Since we are overriding the **keycloak.v2** theme, we add the `parent` field to the properties file, specifying the base theme we are inheriting from. We set it to `keycloak.v2`, so that **myCustomTheme** will inherit the **keycloak.v2** theme for all of its components unless we are overriding something specific.

     `parent=keycloak.v2`
4. This next step required a bit of exploration and trial-and-error of how the default **keycloak.v2** theme is structured, but I found that the place where the Keycloak logo is defined for keycloak.v2 is in `keycloak.v2/admin/resources/logo.svg`. Therefore, for **myCustomTheme**, all one would have to do to use a custom logo that overrides the default `keycloak.v2` one is add a `resources` folder to `/opt/keycloak/themes/myCustomTheme/admin` and add the custom SVG image as a file called `logo.svg`.

   - Note that this is different than what the [Keycloak Docs suggest](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#adding-an-image-to-a-theme), which has you creating the same `resources` folder but also an `img` folder inside of it which would contain your images. I suspect this has to do with the fact that we are overriding an image instead of adding one, and the **keycloak.v2** theme code does not follow its own guide and instead places its logo in `resources` instead of `resources/img`.
5. Start Keycloak, go to the Admin Console, sign in and go to **Realm Settings > Themes > Admin Console theme**, and select **myCustomTheme**.  Refresh and you should see your icon change now.

Below is the results of doing the above, showing my resulting folder structure and the Before/After of replacing the Keycloak logo with [some random SVG I got from public domain](https://publicdomainvectors.org/en/free-clipart/Vector-image-of-green-thumbs-up-hand/22727.html):

- **Folder structure**: https://ibb.co/h9kZqb3
- **Before/After**: https://ibb.co/cJ6t434

Comment: Great tutorial! Just a little thing to be corrected - at the begining you mention (correctly) a path /opt/keycloak/themes/, but then using /opt/keycloak/theme/ - it should be "themes" (in plural).

Comment: What to do if I want to add some pages and links in the keycloak.v2, any guide?

Comment: Works fine in local but when Tried same in Production the image doesn't load, don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

The new admin UI (starting from keycloak 19) has been delivered through keycloak-admin-ui.jar. In order to customize any UI components, it has to be done by forking this [repo](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-ui) and build on your own.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Keycloak custom theme.
Please refer to the documentation in the following link.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes